# Send data or state to another React Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a troubles with my react project.

I need to send some data (or also it can be state (true or false)) to the another page. Im using the react-router-dom.

```
import { useState } from "react"
import ProductToCart from "./ProductToCart"
import Cart from "../../Pages/Cart"

const Buy = () => {
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Add to cart")
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
  const addToCart = () => {
    setIsActive((current) => !current)
    setButtonText("Added to the cart ✓")
    if (isActive) {
      setButtonText("Add to cart")
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        class='buy'
        style={{
          fontSize: isActive ? "0.8rem" : "1rem",
          color: isActive ? "lightgray" : "white",
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          addToCart()
        }}
      >
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Buy
```

After button is pressed/unpressed, I need to send this to the page Cart.js, where I wanna show product in the cart. And do something like:

```
if (value from Buy.js is true) {
do something 
}
```

I already tried `<Link>` but I dont need redirect to Cart.js, I only need to send a value. May be I do something wrong, but if you can tell me just how to send data between the pages **without redirect** it will be fine... thank you!

Comment: passing as props .. or you would want to navigate to cart ?

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a global store for your state. Look into things like https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html -- you can store the object of the item that was stored, and then the Cart.js will listen to those changes and you can change the UI accordingly.

Comment: @KcH Don't think you can pass as props because they're not rendering Cart in this component.

Comment: If your action is add to cart, then better you use Context API. to store cart data,

Comment: @crevulus, yeah seems to be ... when I saw "send data" I thought as props :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, You just have to make the state in parent components a global state and pass the state value to the cart component as props.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Item from "./cart.js";

const Home = () => {
  const [products, addproduct] = useState([]);

  const addToBasket = () => {
    addproduct();// add product here 
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Cart product={products}/> 
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The cart state should likely be global, or otherwise accessible from multiple components.

Because even if you're not on the "buy" page, you will need other pages to be able to navigate to the cart, or view the "count" of items in the cart.

Sounds like you need a state management library!

I'd recommend recoil for this use-case, its very lightweight (unlike other popular options like redux).

https://recoiljs.org/

Simply set up a cart `atom` and append products when the user clicks "buy" then you can use this state in the cart.